# Lightbox not working in Drupal Advanced Poll module

Tags: drupal, lightbox2

I needed a poll to vote on pictures, so I chose Advanced Poll module.
In choices I added html for images together with link to the picture and attributes for lightbox ... this is the code:

```
<a title="picture" rel="lightbox" href="/sites/default/files/pic.jpg" class="lightbox-processed">
<img  class="image image-big image-center" src="/sites/default/files/pic.jpg" title="picture"/>
</a>
```

This same code is used around the web and lightbox is working. I don't understand why it is not working in Advanced Poll. The picture opens in window and not in lightbox.

Do you have any similar experience.
I will really apreciate your help.
Thank you

drupal version is 6.19

advanced poll module is 6.x-1.x-dev

lightbox2 module 6.x-1.9

Answer (score 0):

Update lightbox to 6.x-2.11: http://drupal.org/node/921800

It fixed a compatibility issue with jQuery update.

If that doesn't help, you should use Firebug or another javascript console log to see any errors generated on that page.